# how to convert weekday text to int (in array)? (google sheet)

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have here formula that can easily convert the weekday text like `Sunday` to weekday int to `1`.

```
=MATCH(A2,{"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"},0)
```

My question is how to convert array-text to array-int?

Let's say for example in a cell, I have value `Sunday, Monday`. Do we have a formula for us to get the array for example `{1,2}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About `Let's say for example in a cell, I have value Sunday, Monday. Do we have a formula for us to get the array for example {1,2}?`, I guessed that from your showing formula is used, you might have wanted `7` and `1`. If my understanding is correct, when your sample formula is used, how about the following modification?

#### Modified formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MATCH(TRIM(SPLIT(A1,",")),{"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"},0))
```

- In this case, `Sunday, Monday` is put in cell "A1".

#### Testing:

[image]

#### Note:

- When the following formula is used,

  ```
    ="{"&TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,ARRAYFORMULA(MATCH(TRIM(SPLIT(A1,",")),{"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"},0)))&"}"
  ```

  - When `Sunday, Monday` is put in the cell "A2", `{7,1}` is put to a cell.

Comment: is it possible to have the same output in a cell as wel? One cell we have output `{1,2}`

Comment: @schutte Thank you for replying. About `is it possible to have the same output in a cell as well. One cell we have output {1,2}`, is your expected formula is this? `="{"&TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,ARRAYFORMULA(MATCH(TRIM(SPLIT(A1,",")),{"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"},0)))&"}"` In this case, when `Sunday, Monday` is put in the cell "A2", `{7,1}` is put to a cell.

Comment: that's the answer sir. thank you very much. add that in our answer

Comment: @schutte Thank you for replying. I added it to my answer. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try:

```
="{"&JOIN(",",INDEX(MATCH(SPLIT(A2,", "),TEXT(SEQUENCE(7,1,2),"DDDD"),0)))&"}"
```

- 

[image]

Comment: it would help if you could share a sample demo sheet recreating this scenario so that we can check it out directly and work it out.

Comment: Sheet is kind of big, I'm afraid i can't share it. Anyways, my only question is that how to convert the resulting value `{1,2}` to an array type so it can be use to another formula.